# Can we avoid singularities by embedding the manifold on a bigger space, maybe Euclidean or Riemannian?

Tags: mathematical-physics, singularities

Can singularities be avoided by embedding Riemannian manifold on bigger space, or more specifically black hole singularities can be avoided or not by embedding in any other manifold.

We don't have clear interpretation of physical laws at a singularity. So, can somehow change the Reimannian space by some mapping it onto another manifold and study the law in that manifold? The idea is that if a singularity is mapped to some well behaved point then we can study the law there and make some interpretations.

Comment: Why do you think this would work? What is the purpose of doing this?

Comment: we dont have clear interpretation of law at singularity. so if we can somehow change the reimannian space by some mapping on other manifold and study the law in that manifold, if singularity is mapped to some well behaved point then we can study the law there and make some interpretations.

Comment: I don't know about the general case, but there's [a review of embeddings of the Schwarzschild metric here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1202.1204). Some of them eliminate the central singularity, but only by mapping it to infinity, which is no help from a physical point of view.

Comment: The downvote seems harsh. It is a nice idea that we could eliminate a singularity by embedding the manifold in a higher dimensional space, but I can't see how it could be made to work. Still, it's a fair question.